# Execute icacls command on remote servers

Tags: powershell, acl

Below is code I have which is executing perfectly when ran for individual servers

```
$Hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$CsvData = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Ansible\status_report_2021.csv" | Where-Object{$_.ServerName -eq $Hostname} | Select-Object SystemFolderPath

foreach($path in $CsvData)
{

$path = $path.SystemFolderPath
$path = $path.trim('\')

# break inheritance on the folder and copy ACEs as uninherited
icacls $path /inheritance:d

#remove all BUILTIN\Users granted ACEs
icacls $path /remove:g BUILTIN\Users

#grant only BUILTIN\Users Read&Execute. avoid using (S,GE,GR) = RX.
#(S,GE,GR) is a specific right and icacls would create 2 ACEs.
#same meaning but if we can avoid it's better
icacls $path /grant:r "BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)RX"

#remove SYSTEM
icacls $path /remove:g "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

#grant SYSTEM as Full control on "this folder, subfolder and files"
icacls $path /grant:r "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F"

icacls $path

}
```

Please let me know how to execute these icacls commands for remote servers.

Comment: Does the `ServerName` column (or some other column) in the CSV report contain valid FQDNs?

Comment: ServerName will be same as `$env:COMPUTERNAME` like A92XXXXXXXXX1AP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use a combination of `Group-Object` to group all server names and their `SystemFolderPath` entries in the csv together and loop over these groups.

Inside the loop use `Invoke-Command` to have the `icacls` commands perform on each server.

Something like

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Ansible\status_report_2021.csv" | Group-Object ServerName | ForEach-Object {
    $server = $_.Name
    foreach ($path in ($_.Group.SystemFolderPath | Select-Object -Unique)) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
            param ([string]$path)
            # break inheritance on the folder and copy ACEs as uninherited
            icacls $path /inheritance:d

            # remove all BUILTIN\Users granted ACEs
            icacls $path /remove:g BUILTIN\Users

            # grant only BUILTIN\Users Read&Execute. avoid using (S,GE,GR) = RX.
            # (S,GE,GR) is a specific right and icacls would create 2 ACEs.
            # same meaning but if we can avoid it's better
            icacls $path /grant:r "BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)RX"

            # remove SYSTEM
            icacls $path /remove:g "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

            # grant SYSTEM as Full control on "this folder, subfolder and files"
            icacls $path /grant:r "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F"

            icacls $path
        } -ArgumentList $path.Trim('\')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. one thing, in Invoke-Command we need the `Credential` also right?

Comment: @EmptyCoder Probably yes, unless you happen to be the domain administrator. Otherwise, use `-Credential` to supply usercredentials with admin permissions on the servers

Answer (score 1):

Start by grouping all the CSV entries by server - this way we can send all the affected paths to each individual server at once:

```
$PathsPerServer = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Ansible\status_report_2021.csv" | Group-Object ServerName
```

Now we can use `Invoke-Command` against each distinct server and execute the icacls statements for each relevant path:

```
$PathsPerServer | ForEach-Object {
    # enumerate all the paths for this server, we need to pass them as arguments to Invoke-Command
    $paths = $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand SystemFolderPath | ForEach-Object Trim

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {
        param([string[]]$Paths)

        foreach ($path in $Paths) {
            # break inheritance on the folder and copy ACEs as uninherited
            icacls $path /inheritance:d

            #remove all BUILTIN\Users granted ACEs
            icacls $path /remove:g BUILTIN\Users

            #grant only BUILTIN\Users Read&Execute. avoid using (S,GE,GR) = RX.
            #(S,GE,GR) is a specific right and icacls would create 2 ACEs.
            #same meaning but if we can avoid it's better
            icacls $path /grant:r "BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)RX"

            #remove SYSTEM
            icacls $path /remove:g "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

            #grant SYSTEM as Full control on "this folder, subfolder and files"
            icacls $path /grant:r "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F"

            icacls $path
        }
    } -ArgumentList $paths
}
```